# How can I change the font-size of text in d3-legend?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This may be obvious but I can't find out how to change the size of font for different devices.

The documentation for d3-legend says that it does not use css.

Answer (score 1):

CSS will still work if you select the SVG element containing your legend text. Here's an example in CSS.

```
svg text {
   font-size:1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a problem identifying a unique identifier for a css rule. For example svg text would apply to all text in the svg. I've tried g.cell and g.legendCells but without luck. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: It's hard to provide a css solution without some code or output from your situation. D3 legend might automatically create a class for legend text which you can determine in your browser by inspecting the text element. Then you could select the class in css.

Answer (score 0):

`g.cell text.label { ... }` worked.